# CGAL surface mesh - removing face

Tags: mesh, cgal

1. Does the remove_face method change the mesh indices?

I get a segmentation fault with this code:

```
        auto face_iterator = m.faces_around_target(m.halfedge(v3));

            for (auto i=face_iterator.begin(); i!=face_iterator.end(); i++) {
                m.remove_face(*i);
            }
```

According to my understanding of the documentation, as long as I don't call collect_garbage the faces are only *marked* as removed., therefore no changes to indices. What is happening?

2. Does remove_face, also remove the face halfedges\ makes them point to null_face? It does not seem to do so, and I don't understand why not..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The face is indeed simply marked as removed but its iterator is invalidated by the removal (remember that iterator goes only over non-removed elements).

As stated in the [doc](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh.html#af2311658bf6d730b276b23b5c304f90e): *removes face f from the halfedge data structure without adjusting anything.*
You need to use a higher level function such as [`CGAL::Euler::remove_face()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html#gacfae7ff8e782da55b941e4487e86c738).

Comment: Thank you! CGAL::Euler is exactly what I needed. ended up using CGAL::Euler::remove_center_vertex(), which worked perfectly!